# css progress bar's tab alignment

Tags: css

originally i have a progress bar/tab of 4 but i decided to add 1 more, but when i added up the code for the fifth 'tab.' it won't align with the other 4 instead it goes below first 'tab.' question is, how can i make the fifth tab aligned/inline with the other four tabs?

[original preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuyCa.jpg)

[updated preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TjSw.jpg)

here's the html:

```
        <div class="wizard">
        <div class="wizard-inner">
            <div class="connecting-line"></div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step4" role="tab" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li> 

                <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                    <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" style="pointer-events: none; cursor: default;">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .wizard {
    margin: 20px auto;
    background: #fff;
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 85px;
}

    .wizard .nav-tabs {
        position: relative;
        margin: 4px auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-bottom-color: #e0e0e0;
    }

    .wizard > div.wizard-inner {
        position: relative;
        margin-right:90px;
    }

.connecting-line {
    height: 2px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #FFA53E;
    cursor: default;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

span.round-tab {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
span.round-tab i{
    color:#FFA53E;
}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #F86D18;

}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab i{
    color: #F86D18;
}

span.round-tab:hover {
    color: #333;
    border: 2px solid #333;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li {
    width: 25%;
}

.wizard li:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #F86D18;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.wizard li.active:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-right:-10px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #F86D18;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

    .wizard .nav-tabs > li a:hover {
        background: transparent;
    }

.wizard .tab-pane {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.wizard h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `li` elements are set to 1/4 of width and you are trying to put 5 elements.
Try:

```
.wizard .nav-tabs > li {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Quite alright :) sometimes the answer is hiding right in front of us but we can't see it, glad i could help.